# Transparent image background on WP7 HubTile

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I have a collection of HubTiles with user-selected images. If an image with transparency is selected, the HubTile's background color (PhoneAccentBrush) shows through. Is there a way to style just the photo background to Transparent without altering the animation backgrounds? (Although if the Title is displayed on a transparent background, that's acceptable, but I'd still like the flipside to use the accent color.)

I've done some searching on styling the HubTile, but haven't been successful.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the fastest way to find an answer on the interwebs is to post your question to SO. I found this not two minutes after posting.

Konstantinos Kyriakopoulos has a [blog post](http://studentguru.gr/b/kokyri/archive/2011/12/03/hubtiles-with-transparent-images.aspx) with the template styling I was looking for. I couldn't set the image background to Transparent, but I was able to set it to PhoneBackgroundBrush, which works just as well.

Specifically, I set the Background of the Border in the TitlePanel Grid.